# How to find the ports of multiple ip's

Tags: ip

As you can probably tell im a bit new to Ubuntu, my problem is that i have 5 IP's attached to my server and i want to know how do i find the ports to the IP's assigned, netstat only gives me the ports to my primary IP. (Im running Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Unless you configure the services on your server/computer to *bind* to one of the other IP address and port combinations, its going to either bind to *all* ports, or just to the primary IP address.  Just an FYI, before you start port-scanning everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `nmap` package, then

```
script nmap.log
IP1=""
IP2=""
IP3=""
IP4=""
IP5=""
sudo nmap -P0 -PS -n -sS -p1-65535 -r -T4 $IP1 $IP2 $IP3 $IP4 $IP5
exit
```

The results will be displayed, and saved in `nmap.log`. Since I'm security-aware, I'm having you check all TCP ports on each IP.

While one might think this will take a long time, taking advantage of the fact that all 5 IPs are local, and the fact that almost all of the ports are closed, the scan goes quite quickly.

For example, scanning my single IP address:

```
$ /usr/bin/time --verbose sudo nmap -P0 -PS -n -sS -p1-65535 -r -T4 192.168.100.97

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-09-19 18:45 EDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.100.97
Host is up (0.000019s latency).
Not shown: 65520 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
53/tcp    open  domain
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
113/tcp   open  ident
631/tcp   open  ipp
3000/tcp  open  ppp
4330/tcp  open  unknown
5154/tcp  open  unknown
8080/tcp  open  http-proxy
9191/tcp  open  sun-as-jpda
9292/tcp  open  unknown
9418/tcp  open  git
17500/tcp open  db-lsp
44321/tcp open  unknown
44322/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.74 seconds
    Command being timed: "sudo nmap -P0 -PS -n -sS -p1-65535 -r -T4 192.168.100.97"
    User time (seconds): 1.49
    System time (seconds): 1.57
    Percent of CPU this job got: 39%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:07.76
```

took 7 3/4 seconds. Multiply by 5, and expect about 40 seconds.

Comment: Make a note that **this scan will take a long time**.  Even with a hugely fast network and resources for the scan.  (It takes a long time to scan 65536 ports)

Comment: @thomas-ward: Not if all the IPs are local and most ports are closed.

Comment: Even if local, if the firewall is dropping the packets or forwarding isn't enabled or any of a thousand other reasons you might end up getting hit with a long scan time.  The reliable but slow way is an external scan, not a local scan, because locally there's a ton of firewall issues that could happen (such as blocking `lo` -> `eth#` or similar with a straight DROP rule and not a REJECT)